I have a problem with passing the path data the user selects from the computer through the html input file element
In my Angular application, I am creating a function that allows the user to select an image file from his computer through the input file element and when the path data of that image is retrieved, that path is 'FakePath' due to the feature. security.
Instead I used reader.readAsDataURL(file) to convert it to base64 which can be used to assign the src value of the img element to display the image. Then I passed the base64 string to the backend to save and the database got an error of 'Data too large'.
On the Node backend I tried using:
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb', 
  extended: true
}));

This resolved the other error, but the problem is that because the data is large, calling the API to retrieve the base64 string to assign to the src attribute to display the image is quite slow, making my application slow.
I tried to research and found out that we should not save Base64 strings in the database because it will make our database very heavy because it contains physical files.
I hope experts can help me, what should I do to be able to display the image file that the user has selected on their computer into the img tag and save the src string of that image into the database without problems? About big data causing the application to slow down

Why is Fakepath an issue? Just upload the file directly to the backend without encoding to Base64. Then save it to blob storage somewhere, not within your database, but store the file location in the DB.

Can you provide a bit of code to illustrate and explain this solution more clearly? I'm new so it's a bit vague

You haven't shown us how exactly you are doing this part, "Then I passed the base64 string to the backend to save". Instead of that, you should send the actual content of the file upload field - either by sending the form the "normal" way, or if AJAX is involved, by adding the file input fields to the dataset you are submitting. (Usually involves using FormData.)

best to use formData... ex:  let form = document.getElementById('my_form_id')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);
return this.http.post(this.uploadImageURL, formData)...  Have endpoint save the file (where only code can reach it to prevent deep links, and ensure authorization before serving).  Store the path/filename in DB.  Be in full control of that filename (don't trust user-input)  Then have an endpoint that returns the file according to passed in primary key of that record.
